# Why irreducible manifolds are prime?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

In wikipedia there is a proof for 3-manifolds that I don't understand. It says that if $M$ is an irreducible manifold and we express $M=N_1\sharp N_2$, then $M$ is obtained by removing a ball each from $N_1$ and $N_2$ and then gluing the resulting spheres together. These united spheres form a 2-sphere in $M$, and the fact that $M$ is irreducible means that this sphere must bound a ball. Undoing the gluing operation (how?), either $N_1$ ir $N_2$ is obtained by gluing that ball to the previously removed ball on their borders.

I understand until here. Now, it says: 
This operation though simply gives a 3-sphere. That means that one of the two factors was in fact a trivial 3-sphere.

But why gluing a 2-sphere to one of the factors gives a 3-sphere? I can't understand this part.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not about "gluing a 2-sphere to one of the two factors". Instead its about reconstructing one of the two factors $N_1$ or $N_2$ by gluing two 3-balls together. Here's a bit more detail.

Suppose that $B \subset M$ is the 3-ball bounded by the "united sphere".

Also, for $k \in \{1,2\}$ let $B_k \subset N_k$ be the 3-ball that was removed from $N_k$.

As you say, from irreducibility of $M$ it follows that for either $k=1$ or $k=2$, the manifold $N_k$ is obtained, or is reconstructed, by gluing $B$ and $B_k$. That gluing identifies the 2-sphere boundary of $B$ and the 2-sphere boundary of $B_k$. Any  manifold that is obtained by gluing two 3-balls, identifying their 2-sphere boundaries, is homeomorphic to $S^3$.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but I don't understand this:
"Any manifold that is obtained by gluing two 3-balls, identifying their 2-sphere boundaries, is homeomorphic to $S^3$"
Roughly speaking, I understand this: 
1. First we remove two balls $B_1,B_2$ from $N_1,N_2$  and gluing the resulting spheres.
2. This sphere bounds a ball $B$ in $M$.
3. When we reconstruct $N_1, N_2$, we have first $N_1\setminus B_1 $ and $N_2 \setminus B_2 $, and we must fill one of the "holes" (supose $N_1\setminus B_1 $) with the sphere $B$, identifying the boundaries. Right?

Comment: No, that's not correct. $B$ is **equal to** $N_k \setminus B_k$ for one of $k=1$ or $k=2$. The reason this is true is that $B$ is **equal to** one of the two pieces obtained from $M$ by cutting along a sphere, and those two pieces are $N_1 \setminus B_1$ and $N_2 \setminus B_2$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I think, in your last comment, "The reason this is true is that......" probably you are assuming this *convention/theorem*: codimension zero submanifold is any subset bounded by a codimension one submanifold. Bounded by means its set-topological boundary is that codimension one submanifold. Am I right?